# Mock Component Function in Angular 4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have one function which I am calling in constructor.

Now, in that function I am calling api. As its said that we dont call actual api when we do unit test case. The function which is calling api that is **private** function. So I am not getting how to mock that function.

below is just simple example as i can't write actual code here.

component

```
private readCurrentItem() {
   this.readCurrentItem.getData(this.url.base, pageNumber).subscribe((item)=>{
    // something
   });
}
```

Now this function is called inside constructor of component then how do I mock this function. "readCurrentItem" is kind of common rest service where I pass what type of data we required. So I can't mock readCurrentItem service class.

Thanks